# Compare given date to today's date in shell

Tags: shell, date, compare

I would like to compare a given date

date1=Wed 01 Aug 10:03:52 EDT 2018

to

todays "date" command in shell.

If the given date is OLDER than 7 days of todays date then echo true

Answer (score 1):

In GNU date you can use `date -d "$date1" +%s` to parse the date string and convert it to the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

You can compare this to the result of `date +%s`, which will give you the current date in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a standard `date` format:

```
date1="Tue Sep 25 11:32:09 EDT 2018"

now=$(date +%s)
cond=$(( $(date -d "$date1" +%s) + 7*24*60*60 ))

if [ $now -ge $cond ]
then
    echo True
fi
```

In case of the new unrecognized format in the question (`date1=Wed 01 Aug 10:03:52 EDT 2018`) you can swap the date and month with:

```
date1="Wed 01 Aug 10:03:52 EDT 2018"
date1=$(echo $date1 | sed -E 's/(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).([0-9]{2}).(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)/\1 \3 \2/')
```

The rest is same

In case of other arbitrary format you'll have to unravel it with regexp and transform into [something `date` can recognize.](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-date-syntax.html#General-date-syntax)

`+%s` formats output in seconds.

`-d DATE` uses specified date string instead of current time.

`sed` matches a regexp and replaces it

Comment: Updated my question if you could update your answer please.